# React: RangeError: Invalid time value - DatePicker error after Saving to LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, datepicker, local-storage

My code was working well, until I haven't got to the point that I'm wanted to save data to Local Storage.

The code fell apart once I added:

```
function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    try {
        const serialzedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serialzedState === null) return undefined;
        return JSON.parse(serialzedState);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

It is a issue with DatePicker and parsing the dates, but I'm not able to figure out how in my code. In comments is the Sandbox link... Which seems to be working.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dan-3c2kp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the `DeadlineList.js` component to display the date. `Intl.DateTimeFormat` was not receiving a proper date object. That caused your issue.

```
{new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US").format(new Date(value))}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-moon-2ncwi)